# Replace a micro switch with the correct type of transistor

Tags: transistors, switches, dc

Below is a micro switch used on an existing circuit, which turns on/off a load in a DC circuit.  I'd like to replace the micro switch with a transistor, since I'm controlling the load using an Arduino which uses a high/low, and not a tristate.  But I don't know how to look for a compatible transistor.  The specifications on this micro switch seems to work for both AC and DC, despite having "VDC" listed in the specifications.  The circuit I'm working with has a load which only needs 3V.

What type of transistor should I use instead of this micro switch?

**Micro Switch:**

L62,Micro Switch 15A,125 or 250 VAC 3/4 HP 125 VAC 1 1/2 HP 250 VAC NC

https://www.ebay.com/itm/L62-Micro-Switch-15A-125-or-250-VAC-3-4-HP-125-VAC-1-1-2-HP-250-VAC-NC-1PL29750-/182962174497

Comment: When you say your load needs "3V" is that AC, or DC? And can you give an upper bound on the current (power) the load demands? Is the load inductive? Be much more specific if you want to receive useful answers.

Comment: The load is 3V DC.  I will try to get it on Monday.  It's not inductive.  If it is, it's negligible.  It'll be a pretty tiny amperage because 2AA batteries will last up to 6 months.  I don't have the data sheet, but I can probably get it.

Comment: Which "Arduino" are you using? There are multiple Arduino boards with differing logic voltage levels (e.g., 3v3 logic, 5v logic).

Comment: Mine uses 5v logic... Arduino UNO R3

Comment: You'll need to determine the current through the load when the load is ON.  Once you know that, find a transistor that can handle at least double that current through its collector-emitter path (BJT) or drain-source path (N-MOSFET). For small-signal BJTs, Beta(sat) is usually around 10; refer to the chosen transistor's data sheet.  There are many how-to documents that describe how to design a transistor switch using BJTs. For example perform a search for "how to use a transistor as a switch". The particular article that I recommend is published on the "Nuts and Volts" website.

Comment: One more comment. If you're using a BJT as your switch, when calculating the resistance value for the (current-limiting) base resistor RB, use the "worst case" voltage for a logic HIGH output voltage, which is usually called VOH (the minimum voltage for a logic HIGH output signal). VOH's value can be found on the ATmega328P's data sheet in the "Electrical Specifications" section.